# How to send a variable through a onclick event?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have created an array.
this array creates buttons with specific and commons attributes.
after appending them to `div(id=form2)` I give them an on click function `gold_2`.
All is working fine but I can't capture the id or value of the button that is eventually clicked.

When I define `btn.onclick=gold_2(value)` to export variable value the function executes link I have already clicked the button.
when I define `btn.onclick=gold_2` I can't capture the button **id/value** that I click.

```
var gold_item = ['CL', 'LR', 'GR', 'TP', 'JH', 'CH', 'HR', 'CK', 'BA', 'BL', 'CP', 'MG', 'XY', 'SC', 'BC', 'PS', 'MS', 'KL', 'DM', 'NP', 'PN', 'DN', 'GC', 'RG', 'CD'];

for (var i = 0; i < gold_item.length; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  //btn.innerHTML=goldItem[i];
  btn.className = "form2_button";
  btn.id = gold_item[i];
  btn.value = gold_item[i];
  btn.innerHTML = gold_item[i];
  var value = gold_item[i];
  document.getElementById('form2').appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = gold_2, 'value';
}

function gold_2() {
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value
  alert(val);
}
```

Comment: your gold_2 function doesn't even take an argument, so, why try to pass one?

Comment: but `btn.onclick = () => gold_2('value');` will do it

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `this` and `addEventListener` without passing `value`

The problem is that you are using comma operator b/w `gold_2` and `"value"`. The whole expression will evaluate to the last expression i.e `"value"`.

I would suggest you using eventListeners rather than directly changing the function

```
btn.addEventListener('click',gold_2);
```

Second problem is that `id` is `undefined` inside `gold_2`. You can use `this` to access the element

```
function gold_2() {
  var val = this.value
  alert(val);
}
```

As you are setting the `value` as the value of element so you don't need to pass it as argument. `this` in `gold_2` will be the element clicked so you can access its value.

#### Using Wrapper function to pass variable

If you still want to pass `value` variable to `gold_2` you can use wrapper function. Also remove `''` around `value`

```
btn.onclick = () => gold_2(value);
```

You will then also need to accept a variable inside function `gold_2`

```
function gold_2(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

Comment: @ManishAgrawal Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @ManishAgrawal You will see a little tick icon below the upvotes. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @ManishAgrawal See the link. Maybe it explain you how to accept the answer